# ERROR: Procfile does not exist, and problems starting web processes

Tags: node.js, heroku

So, I'm currently following this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs to start a simple Node.js app. I've got to the part where foreman is used to run the app locally (under Declaring process types with Procfile), and I'm getting an error telling me that the Procfile does not exist. My Procfile is in the same directory as my code, etc. All of the steps up till now have been fine. I skipped past this part in the tutorial to try and run the application on Heroku, but this line `heroku ps:scale web=1` under Visit your application tells me that there is "No such type as web"... I'm using Windows to develop my app. Any help would be much appreciated. :-)

EDIT: `web: node web.js` is the contents of the Procfile, and I'm following the tutorial so I assume it's being committed... could you check the tutorial please and tell me if it is?

Comment: You should post the contents of your Procfile so we can see if there's anything wrong with it. Also, are you sure you didn't somehow forget to add and commit the Procfile to your project's git repo?

Comment: @meetamit I've edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: first you can try to start foremann locally, with `foreman start`. This should start your app. Second you can add your whole directory with `git add .`and `git commit -m"some message"`. Then you can do a `git push heroku master`. Please check that your Procfile has a capital "P", otherwise unix-like system's won't recognize it as such.

Answer (score 27):

I had also received the `Procfile does not exist` error.  The issue with mine was that I had left the '.txt' extension on the file.  Once I removed the file extension and ran the `foreman start` it worked perfectly, hope this help =)

Comment: I had the same issue. Removing the extenision in finder on the mac didn't actually remove it either so I had to do it from the terminal with mv Procfile.txt Procfile

Comment: @ddollar you getting this? Can anyone point this out to him please?

Comment: Seems obvious but make sure you are running the command from the correct directory! :grin: