# Node app in heroku runs locally but I cannot scale dynos

Tags: heroku, procfile

I'm trying to run a node app in heroku. Foreman works to run it locally, and it pushes to git without any errors. However, when I run `heroku ps:scale web=1`, it says there is no such type as web. My Procfile is just this line: web: node server.js, which I think should work to set the web type.

Does anyone know why this could be going wrong? Your help would be appreciated!

Here's a copy of the terminal...

```
jmm-2:supportEmail jamesmatheson$ foreman start
14:35:07 web.1  | started with pid 36298
14:35:08 web.1  | app is running on /removed port/
14:35:08 web.1  | database open
^CSIGINT received
14:35:09 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
14:35:09 web.1  | exited with code 1
jmm-2:supportEmail jamesmatheson$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    No such type as web.
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323633/error-procfile-does-not-exist-and-problems-starting-web-processes

Answer (score -2):

Specity --app APP_NAME (As given in My Apps in Heroku). Just answered same questions here:
[Heroku Web Dyno failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368861/heroku-web-dyno-failing)